# Is it possible to seek to a random position in streaming audio (using Flash Media Server and Flash 9)?

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, flash-media-server

I am creating an audio player that has a feature to sample a random 30-sec preview of the music for the listeners (server-side is Flash Media Server and client side is Flash 9).  Can this be done in Actionscript 3 or must the samples be prepared ahead of time?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality would have to be coded into the server to serve out 30 random seconds of the content.  The client can only consume whatever the server feeds it and in order for the client to serve out 30 random seconds of the file it would need to whole file buffered locally to support this.